# EPERM during gulp commands

Tags: node.js, gulp, file-permissions, browser-sync

I have a gulpfile that I am using together with Browserify, Babelify and BrowserSync to implement my build workflow. However, I am constantly having problems with `EPERM` errors in Node.js.

I first had an error in my `gulp clean` task that used [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) in order to clean my `dist` directory. The task would occasionaly throw an error (I was not able to reproduce the error 100% of attempts though). The error was an `EPERM` that complained about the `unlink` action for `./dist/app.js`. I tried using [del](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del) instead of rimraf and for some reason it helped.

However, if I run `gulp watch` and something changes , there is very often this error now:

```
(node:10740) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[22:52:35] Using gulpfile D:\Workspace\milestones\gulpfile.js
[22:52:35] Starting 'clean'...
[22:52:35] Finished 'clean' after 4.2 ms
[22:52:35] Starting 'build-persistent'...
[22:52:37] Finished 'build-persistent' after 1.55 s
[22:52:37] Starting 'watch'...
[22:52:37] Finished 'watch' after 92 ms
[BS] Local URL: http://localhost:3000
[BS] External URL: http://192.168.0.108:3000
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[22:52:48] Starting 'clean'...
[22:52:48] Finished 'clean' after 2.77 ms
[22:52:48] Starting 'build-persistent'...
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\Workspace\milestones\dist\app.js'
at Error (native)
```

The full gulpfile may be seen in the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/valorl/a737f2dd83ed374abfc01c731e25696c).

I am running Windows 10.

**Update:** The issue seems to be absent when running `gulp build` and therefore might be caused by BrowserSync.

Comment: Which OS? What is the status of the file in question (deleted or present)? Have you checked for open issues at the maintainer?

Comment: I am on Windows 10. Since the clean was successful , I assume the file in question is a newly created file during the `build-persistent` task. I haven't checked for open issues as I am not sure what code is this originating in since I also had problems with rimraf for example. Additionslly, I had the same both problems on my Windows 7 machine at work. I have also noticed that if I just do `gulp build` it runs without the error, which would mean that this problem might be related to BrowserSync.

Comment: This Problem is most likely because of the Editor Atom.io locking certain directories/files when opened in the tree view. more information here: - https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4oqhmu/eperm_in_gulp_dist_folder/ - https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3365

Comment: Ok, I have played around with it and Atom is definitely not responsible for this. I have tried running `gulp watch` while everything is closed and then edit it in notepad, still got  ` Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\Workspace\milestones\dist\app.js' at Error (native)`. Even tried using `gulp-chmod` to set the permissions of `app.js` before the pipe to `gulp.dest(...)`

Comment: Came across this, since our offshore team just started recently having issues with EPERM showing up during our normal Gulp tasks that haven't been changed in months. Their issue seems to be that something is causing the files to be marked as read-only at the dest during each write.  They tried removing read-only and then running the tasks and it gets set again.  Would you mind checking if your files are now being set to read-only?

Comment: The `dist` folder has the read-only flag square-checked (only some files in it are read-only) but if I check the `app.js` and `style.css` files in it , they are not read-only. The `modify` permissions are allowed on all of them for Administrators which I am (and I am running my shell as admin as well). If I do `ls -al` in git bash, the permissions for the `dist` directory are `drwxr-xr-x` and for `app.js` are `-rw-r--r--` if that can be trusted in anyway since it is unix style permissions on windows...